# inspect.getfullargspec in the python

Tags: python

I found this code in a book:

```
def example(a:int ,b=1,*c,d,e=2,**f)-> str :
    pass

import inspect
print(inspect.getfullargspec(example))
```

And it prints:

```
FullArgSpec(args=['a', 'b'], varargs='c', varkw='f', defaults=(1,), kwonlyargs=['d', 'e'], kwonlydefaults={'e': 2}, annotations={'return': <class 'str'>, 'a': <class 'int'>})
```

In the arguments, `b` and `e` both have default values, so why there is only `b`'s default value (`1`) in `defaults`?

I also read the documentation, where I saw:

```
FullArgSpec(args, varargs, varkw, defaults, kwonlyargs, kwonlydefaults, annotations)
```

Is this order important (`args`, `varargs`, `varkw`, ...)?

Comment: `e`'s default is in `kwonlydefaults={'e': 2}`.

Comment: so why it's just shown there not in defaults.

Comment: ...because it's a keyword-only argument, and keyword-only arguments' defaults go in `kwonlydefaults`.

Comment: b=1 is a keyword-only argument too.

Comment: No, it isn't. If you call `example(1, 2, ...)` then the `2` will go to `b` without specifying the keyword.

Answer (score 0):

As @jonrsharpe mentioned, the `e` is a [keyword only argument](https://peps.python.org/pep-3102/) . The reason is that it is defined after `*c` (a positional argument with variable length) and this marks the beginning of the keyword only arguments.

That is why its value appears in `kwonlydefaults` when inspecting the function.